# How do I print specific values in a key:value list from a YAML file?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, yaml

I've just switched over from bash scripting to python, an am trying to understand the language by writing some code; please excuse my python ignorance.

I'm trying to determine how to pull specific key, and values from a YAML file.

ex.

```
import yaml

stream = open('test.yaml', 'r')
data = yaml.load(stream)

abc = data['yaml_key']
```

gives me something like:

```
{'1': 'a', '2': 'b', '3': 'c'}
```

How do I print specific key:values? I was hoping that it would act like a tuple, and I could just do something like:

```
abc[0]
```

etc. But unfortunately, when I try to print out abc[#], it just prints out abc[#], but printing out abc, gives me the key:value list.

This is probably an easy one for anyone experienced in Python, but any input would be appreciated.

Comment: use `abc["1"],abc["2"]` etc..

Comment: `abc = print data['yaml_key']` isn't valid syntax. Is this your actual code?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: i get
----> 1 print abc["2"]
KeyError: '2'

Comment: @sweeneyrod that was syntax mistake on my part, the code does not use print.

Comment: then your dict does not look like `{'1': 'a', '2': 'b', '3': 'c'}`, when you `print abc` what do you see?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: very odd, that is my variable output.
>>> print abc
>>> {'1': 'a', '2': 'b', '3': 'c'}

Comment: Are you definitely doing `abc["2"]` or `abc['2']`, not `abc[2]`?

Comment: that is strange as you can see `print({'1': 'a', '2': 'b', '3': 'c'}["2"])` outputs `b`

Comment: Apologies, I had a different set of key:values, it was a bad example used on my part, as I had the abc["values"] listed as integers, and not the key value. It does work when using the correct key. Thank you!!

Comment: no worries, if you have a key that you are not sure if it will be in the dict or not you can use `dict.get(your_key)` which returns None by default if the key does not exist

Answer (score 1):

Contribution belongs to Padraic for his comment, but for future reference, the correct method to loading key:values is:

```
abc["key_value"]
```

Also worth noting in his response, the following:

```
abc.keys() // list keys
abc.get("key_value") // get specific key value
```